# Triggers on views in PostgreSQL 9.0

Tags: postgresql, triggers, view

In PostgreSQL 9.1 it's simple:

```
CREATE TRIGGER koncerty_insert INSTEAD OF INSERT ON Koncerty FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE koncerty_insert();
```

But now I have to create a trigger for view in PostgreSQL 9.0, I can no longer use `INSTEAD OF`.. In fact, as far as I know, I cant use triggers on views at all.

Is there a simple way to create a trigger for view?

Comment: The solution for older versions is to use a RULE: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createrule.html But this is a good reason to upgrade ;)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Are you sure about that? Because when i create that RULE as: `CREATE RULE koncerty_insert AS ON INSERT TO Koncerty DO SELECT koncerty_insert();` After inserting a row into a view I've got an error, that for views i must use unconditional `ON INSERT DO INSTEAD` rule.. and in documentation there is no such an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL 9.0 you must use [`RULE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrule.html)s.

If at all possible, upgrade instead. Rules are surprisingly hard to get right.